# Troubles modifying WordPress Roots theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I was told that if I would use Roots theme for wordpress, it would save me time and nerves if I develop wordpress sites. However, I'm unable to do any modifications on the theme, the style.css is not included on the site, and even if I include it after the other stylesheets, it wont do anything, as I've tried maybe the simplest thing ever:

```
h1{display:none;}
```

I've also tried reading the docs at https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/doc/README.md
and bootstrap documentation http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html but I'm still unable to do any modifications. I don't dare to modify the bootstrap.css itself, so how I'm supposed to modify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any css style you want but you have to add it in the assets/css/app.css file located in the theme's folder.

You were right about not modifying bootstrap.css or any other core files. Just modify:

1. for your css styles additions you edit the assets/css/app.css
2. for your .js custom additions you edit the assets/js/main.js and you put any javascript plugin inside assets/js/plugins.js
3. for your .php custom additions to the theme (like php functions) you edit lib/custom.php (Or you can also create new files and include theme)

This way you can correctly update the theme.

If it still doesn't get applied the reason could be css specificity.

Here's some more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

As a final resort you can use:
h1{display:none !important;}

Use this temporary until you find a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain me why I can't just add the original style.css to head.php and modify it? Because doing modifications in the app.css did do the trick.

Comment: app.css is the last css file added and since in CSS last rule gets applied app.css will be applied. Style.css doesn't contain any css rules in Roots. Adding in app.css is just the way Roots keeps track of the custom css styles.

Comment: It's easier to update too. Knowing were all your custom modifications are you ca just replace all the other files without breaking the theme.

Comment: But to answer your question. You should add any other css files in the scripts.php not head.php. Adding it in the head.php will get overridden by the style rules in the bootstrap.css. Why? Cause scripts.php is included after head.php. Also in scripts.php, app.css is after bootstrap.css that's why app.css will be applied last as I said before.

Comment: If app.css is loaded after bootstrap.css why does sometimes you have to use !important? It happens whenever i want to change background colours nd stuff.

Comment: Not sure if I understand 100% your question but probably because you are not writing good css. Even though app.css is after bootstrap.css, specificity still applies. The css style in the bootstrap.css are probably more specific than the css styles you wrote in app.css. You should be able to find out instantly with Firebug the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use !important unless you really have no other choice (and that should be rare).  The reason that your custom styles don't get applied is that the CSS "specificity" is dictating that other rules are more relevant/important than your custom one.  Make your custom CSS rule more "important" than Bootstrap's and your style will show up.

Here's some more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

EDIT: This was meant as a reply to the last post in the other thread, but I have no idea how to reply to that one.  I'm new!  Apologies!

Comment: You cannot add comments to other peoples' posts with your amount of reputation (so don't be too shocked, if you get some harsh responses to doing so). Posting answers for anything else than answering the original question is not well seen. Hang in, after some answers/questions you will be able to comment.